# Pros and cons connecting R2R directly to FPGA/CPLD

Tags: video, programmable-logic, vga

I am designing the R2R-based DAC circuit (5 bits per channel) for the video output @ 25.17 MHz. Looking for advice to ensure I didn't overlook something very important.

1. Initial design was CPLD -> LVC16374 -> R2R with 75 Ohm output impedance. The con is if data for different bits arrives into the R2R with delay, there will be very short spikes in the output. Therefore need filter.
2. Second design CPLD -> LVC16374 -> R2R with relatively high impedance (e.g. 1.5k) -> THS7136. The output video buffers have filters, the power consumption is comparable to design #1.
3. At this stage I am not sure LVC16374 is required at all. It is possible R2R having resistance to satisfy CPLD output current specification. CPLD is fast enough (EPM3064A-4 of 4.5 ns) to have all bits arrive more or less in time.

And by the way, I plan to pass VS and HS through 1G79, it seems 3.3V sync signals must be well received by the VGA monitors, and I didn't find if there's need for 75 Ohm impedance matching (if there is a need, there will never be 5 or 3.3V on the line?).

So the question - is the design #3 looks appropriate? Any issues you may see? Or suggest better idea?

**Further research:**

[image]

[image]

Both pictures have large scale, not possible to figure out what is going on small currents, and what device performs better. This is actually vitally important for the R2R network.

To be honest it is kind of unexpected to see LVC logic output voltage not being kept flat at nominal on specific range of the currents (sunk or sourced). Of course, the effect is fully understandable from physics point of view, maybe there're other types of gates providing required constant voltage over the current range?

**Edit:** one of the [projects](https://tigerente-lab.com/fpga-based-r-2r-audio-dac-audio-digital-to-analog-converter/) available on the subject. 24-bit R2R DAC, however for audio. Resistor values seem to be in hundreds of the Ohms (R ~ 200 Ohms?), I wonder on accuracy of the DAC and power being consumed - and how much CPLD likes it.

Comment: If the CPLD can drive the current, and resistances are high enough that varying CPLD output impedances are small enough, then I don't see why it would not work - but I can't make that as an answer. For the syncs, they are 5V TTL levels, so 3.3V output should be fine, but again, I don't guarantee it. The de facto way of terminating the syncs at monitor is 2k2 to ground, and there may be some capacitance too, but you never know if someone uses coaxial cable for the sync wires too. It might be best to have 75 ohm or larger resitor in series to drive the sync outputs.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding syncs - I will leave placeholder for the resistor. 2.2k info is new for me, with 75 Ohm series the final voltage at the receiving end should be 3.19 V >> 2 V TTL.